# 2 Foreign Keys, 1 Navigation Property to pull through both

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco

Given the following rough code-first schema, the goal would appear to be quite simple. An `Invoice` can either be from or to a `Company`, and the `Invoices` collection should contain all invoices regardless of which it is.

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FromCompanyId { get; set; }
    public int ToCompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company FromCompany { get; set; }
    public virtual Company ToCompany { get; set; }
}
```

You'll note in a Migration that a third `Company_Id` is generated for obvious reasons to support the `Invoices` navigation property as EF only *appears* to support a 1 Nav Prop -> 1 FK arrangement.

My question is whether or not it is possible to have the `Invoices` property contain both, or if I should map them individually (ie. `IC<Inv> InvoicesFrom`, `IC<Inv> InvoicesTo`) and create a client-side collection to have both manually.

I have tried:

1. Using `InverseProperty` on both `FromCompany` and `ToCompany`, which confuses EF as it can't determine the principal end of the relationship.

   ```
   [ForeignKey(nameof(FromCompanyId)), InverseProperty(nameof(Company.Invoices))]
   public virtual Company FromCompany { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey(nameof(ToCompanyId)), InverseProperty(nameof(Company.Invoices))]
   public virtual Company ToCompany { get; set; }
   ```
2. Using fluent API to map them, but it only takes into account the second which makes sense from a code perspective.

   ```
       modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
           .HasMany(m => m.Invoices)
           .WithRequired(m => m.ToCompany)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
       modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
           .HasMany(m => m.Invoices)
           .WithRequired(m => m.FromCompany)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
   ```

There's of course no major issue if this isn't possible, I just could have sworn I've done it before.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, here is a complete version of the workaround to maintain an `IEnumerable<Invoices>` from company that contains both of the sets put together.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(c => c.InvoicesFrom).WithRequired(i => i.FromCompany).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(c => c.InvoicesTo).WithRequired(i => i.ToCompany).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }

    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Invoice> InvoicesFrom { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Invoice> InvoicesTo { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Invoice> Invoices
    {
        get {
            return InvoicesFrom.Union(InvoicesTo);
        }
    }
}

public class Invoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FromCompanyId { get; set; }
    public int ToCompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company FromCompany { get; set; }
    public virtual Company ToCompany { get; set; }
}
```